# Visual Studio 2015 - Cannot debug line by line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

NET application line by line. This is happening for few of the variables. I cannot hover over them to see the values or expand them to see the properties. And while in running mode when i try to add that variable to watch i get a error saying 'VariableName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Not sure what the root cause of this error, but you may try to  Clean/Rebuild Solution. But If it's the variable scope issue, please research it and fix this in your code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx   anyway please feel free to share your code here

Comment: @ssuhas76, I remember that I got this issue before, you'd better to check the debugging settings under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General like "Use managed/unmanaged compatibility mode" or others. View the result for the variable.

Comment: @ssuhas76, Could you debug your app now? Would  you please share us the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi Jack, It is still the same issue

Comment: Something weird is happening. 

I cannot hover over the OracleCommand variable. I cannot even see in the watch. I have defined as Dim cmd As New OracleCommand. When I add it to watch it says

'cmd' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level